# Looking for a CKFinder connector for images stored in SQL Server binary data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wysiwyg, ckfinder

I'm looking for a connector for CKFinder that will enable it to use images stored in a SQL Server database as binary data. Google has turned up much and I was wondering if perhaps done anything like this and can refer me to some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an official one, there isn't a one and it looks like there will not be one. I created [a trac ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10619) for this and it got rejected.

They are kind of right in that it's complicated to write a generic connector, because the backend could be MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle or any other SQL server running on any platform.

Backups and migrations aside, the best reason to use an SQL backend (at least for me) is for storing metadata and that would still require some custom SQL, because they could have no idea what I want to store and how.

I know this is not a solution so -1 if you feel like it. I have not found any instructions other than the official [Server Side Integration guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Server_Side_Integration) mentioned in the ticket.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a handler.  You are trying to read a binary image from a database and serve it to a user (or page - depending on the need).
You can see an example here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/08/27/25568.aspx

It would help to know who -or what- is going to consume the image.  Are you creating an image store?  So at that point you would reference the Handler in your web.config and then create a Gridview or DataList that references the images and the Handler will render them for you at runtime.

Comment: I know how to do all that. I just need to hook it up to the CKFinder.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, that's why -1